# To what former status of Rabbi Eliezer did Rabbi Yehoshua return the law?

Tags: maseches-niddah

It says in Nida (7) that during Rabbi Eliezer's life the Halacha was not followed according to his opinion (his opinion in the Mishna is that four woman receive the status of *dayan shaytan*). However, after his death the Halacha was followed according to his opinion.

> כל ימיו של רבי אליעזר היו עושין כרבי יהושע לאחר פטירתו של רבי אליעזר החזיר רבי יהושע את הדבר ליושנו כרבי אליעזר בחייו מ"ט לא
>   משום דרבי אליעזר שמותי הוא וסבר
>   אי עבדינן כוותיה בחדא עבדינן כוותיה באחרנייתא ומשום כבודו דר"א לא מצינן מחינן בהו
>   לאחר פטירתו של ר"א דמצינו מחינן בהו החזיר את הדבר ליושנו
>
> All of Rabbi Eliezer's days, they would act according to Rabbi Yehoshua's opinion. After Rabbi Eliezer's death, Rabbi Yehoshua returned the law to its former status. Why could't the law follow Rabbi Eliezer during his life? Because Rabbi Eliezer was banned, and it had been thought, if we follow him in this one law, we might end of following him in other laws. Since we have great honor for Rabbi Eliezer we would't be able to protest his other laws. However, after Rabbi Eliezer's death, when we are able to protest his other laws, Rabbi Yehoshua returned the law to its former status.

To what former status was the law returned to? The text itself reads that the law did not follow Rabbi Eliezer during his life, if so there was no former status to be returned to.

---

This is the question of Rashah if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Yerushalmi's congruent version can answer this.

Translations in **bold**.

> אמר רבי יהושע לא שמעתי אלא בתולה אבל הלכה כרבי ליעזר. אין אומרין מי שלא ראה את הלבנה יבוא ויעיד אלא אומר מי שראה את הלבנה יבוא ויעיד אתה לא שמעת אני שמעתי כל ימים שהיה ר' ליעזר קיים היתה הלכה כרבי יהושע **משמת רבי ליעזר הנהיג רבי יהושע הלכה כרבי ליעזר.** מה נן קיימין אם בששמע רבי ליעזר מפי אחד ורבי יהושע מפי שנים בין בחיים בין לאחר מיתה תהא הלכה כרבי יהושע ואם בששמע רבי יהושע מפי אחד ורבי ליעזר מפי שנים בין בחיים בין לאחר מיתה תהא הלכה כר' ליעזר כהדא דתני אחד אומר שמעתי מפי שנים ושנים אומרים שמענו מפי אחד ייפה כח האחד ששמע מפי שנים מכח השנים ששמעו מפי אחד אלא כן אנן קיימין בשוין זה שמע מפי אחד וזה שמע מפי אחד זה שמע מפי שנים וזה שמע מפי שנים **בחייו לא ראה דעתו לאחר מיתתו ראה דעתו**
>
> When Rabbi Eliezer died, Rabbi Yehoshua acted like Rabbi Eliezer... During Rabbi Eliezer’s life he did not agree with him, after his death he agreed with him.

As Pnei Yehoshua explains, they only disagreed on a basis of logic, during Rabbi Eliezer’s lifetime Rabbi Yehoshua did not agree with him logically. After his death he conceded to him with regards to this dispute, so he starting acting like Rabbi Eliezer.

So, the Yerushalmi seems to be saying that he only started following Rabbi Eliezer’s law after his death, and that prior they disagreed.

According to Mevo Hatalmud (33 end), although the Talmud Yerushalmi was written by Rabbi Yochanan, the Agaddic portions were added in later. Perhaps this version is more correct than the Bavli.

> וע״כ דאע״ג דר״י חיבר הירושלמי, מ״מ האגדות ירושלמי נספחו בזמן אחרון

Meaning that since the law was never like Rabbi Eliezer during his life, it couldn’t be restored to that opinion. Rather, it was a new beginning of following his opinion.